# How can I make a calculation in a python form using combo box within a notebook?

Tags: python, forms, combobox, tkinter

sorry for bothering you again with my newbie problems in Python. I am trying to make a simple calculation (multiplication) in python using combobox and I don't know how. Below you will find what I have done so far with no success. Hope you can help me!

Thank you very much in advance

Here is my code:

```
import Tkinter

root = Tk()
root.title("Model A")
root.minsize(400, 220)
root.maxsize(410, 240)

# start of Notebook (multiple tabs)
notebook = ttk.Notebook(root)
notebook.pack(fill='both', expand='yes')
notebook.pressed_index = None

# child frames
frameOne = Tkinter.Frame(notebook, bg='white',width=560, height=100)

frameOne.pack(fill='both', expand=True)
# pages
notebook.add(frameOne, text='Simple calculation')

#Close Application Button
def quit(root):
    root.destroy()
tk.Button(root, text="Close Application", command=lambda root=root:quit(root)).pack()

## Calculation
def defocus(event):
    event.widget.master.focus_set()
def multiply(*args):
    try:
        product.config(round(float(Num_One.get())*float(Num_Two.get())))
    except ValueError:
        pass

## variables
Num_One = StringVar()
Num_Two = StringVar()
product = DoubleVar()
#Number One
ttk.Label(frameOne, text="Select First Number:").grid(column =3, row = 0)
NumOne_Select = Combobox(frameOne, values=("1", "2", "3","4", "5"),textvariable=Num_One)
NumOne_Select.grid(column=4, row=0, columnspan="5", sticky="nswe")
NumOne_Select.bind('<KeyPress>', multiply)
NumOne_Select.bind('<KeyRelease>', multiply)

#Number two
ttk.Label(frameOne, text="Select Second Number:").grid(column =3, row = 6 )
NumTwo_Select = Combobox(frameOne, values=("1", "2", "3","4", "5"),textvariable=Num_Two)
NumTwo_Select.grid(column=4, row=6, columnspan="5", sticky="nswe")
NumTwo_Select.bind('<KeyPress>', multiply)
NumTwo_Select.bind('<KeyRelease>', multiply)

# display results
ttk.Label(frameOne, text = "Product:").grid(column = 3, row = 8)
ttk.Label(frameOne, textvariable=product).grid(column = 4, row = 8)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: This can't be your actual code. You use things from `Tkinter` with no module name, with `Tkinter`, and with `tk`, and you use things from `ttk` with and without the module name. So to make this even start up, you'd have to do something like `import Tkinter; import Tkinter as tk; from Tkinter import *; import ttk; from ttk import *`. Please give us an actual [SSCCE](http://sscce.org) if you want us to debug your code.

Comment: I wasn't suggesting you actually add all those crazy imports. Just `import Tkinter` and `import ttk` once each, and use the contents in a consistent way. It's much harder to read this way.

Comment: Also, it's not a good idea to change your question to match an answer. These questions are supposed to be useful to people who come along in the future with the same problem. Now, someone who's got the same problem as you (binding `<KeyPress>` and `<KeyRelease>` only) will never find your question, because it's no longer asking that. If you have a followup question after fixing your code, create a new question for the followup (and add links between them). You _should_ fix the code to be what you actually had before (so it runs and can be tested); you should _not_ fix it to match the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your code doesn't actually run, I can't tell you what all of the problems are with it… but I can spot two pretty easily.

First, in `multiply`, you're doing `product.config`. That's not how you the value of a `DoubleVar`. You almost certainly want `product.set` here.

Second, you're trying to catch all changes with `<KeyRelease>`. If you, say, paste from the clipboard with the mouse, or change the value by using the pulldown menu, nothing will get updated because there's no key release event.

You're also binding `<KeyPress>` for some reason. In normal use, this means for each keypress you update `Product` with the old value, then immediately update it again with the new value. If someone's holding down a key until it repeats, you'll keep updating, but always be one repeat behind.

If you want to try to do things this way, I believe you'll need to bind at least these events:

- `<KeyRelease>` (and not `<KeyPress>`)
- `<<ComboboxSelected>>`
- `<<Clear>>`
- `<<Cut>>`
- `<<Paste>>`

So, what other way is there to do it? Well, there are a few, and I'm really not sure which is most pythonic (or Tk-ish?); Tk is one of the few areas of Python where TOOWTDI doesn't hold. But I think I'd do it by hooking the update of each `StringVar`, instead of each `Combobox`. Just throw out the `bind` calls, and instead do this:

```
Num_One.trace("w", multiply)
Num_Two.trace("w", multiply)
```

Comment: Dear Abarnert, thanks for your prompt response... As you can see, the code is already updated and it also includes the recommendations you proposed me, however, I have already tried and the problem remains. The second way you explained is quite confuse for me, I don't really understand it since I am really newbie... can you give me an example which shows what you said before?. Thanks for your time and effort. Hector!

Comment: Dear Abarnert, I tried "Num_One.trace("w", multiply)"and "Num_Two.trace("w", multiply)", including the previous comments and suggestions and now works properly... Thank you very much!!!

Comment: Do you still have a question about how `StringVar.trace` works? I can explain it in more detail, and link to the appropriate documentation, if you need it.

Comment: Dear Abarnert, I didn't want to confuse you neither changing the code without leaving the first problem, but I am also new to stackoverflow and I don't know how it does really work when the code needs to be updated. I will try to do it the next time, I am so sorry for my mess....

Comment: Actually the code is working perfect, it has not problem at all, but I have many other questions I would like to ask if you don't mind. The question I have is related to putting a frame into a notebook form in tkinter. I already have the code for both, but not how to merge them into only one. If you want I can make another question based on this. Thank you very much!

Comment: @Hector: That definitely sounds like something that should be a separate question.